# Write values to CCK field from content type Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm using Drupal 6, I try to developed my own Drupal module. I can retrieve a node from the database in my module. Now I want to try to write some values for example number 6 to a CCK field for example field_grade_student.
I try to this this the following way, here I try to assign the student the number. Another number can priviously be assigned so I add it.. . But if i look to the database nothing is happen? must I write a database query to solve this issue or what i'm doing wrong?
My question is, how can write values to cck field without a sql query?

```
foreach($currentArray as $value) { // $currentArray is node student.
    $value->field_grade_student[0]['value'] += 6;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you mean "without using a manual sql query", since to update a node a db query has to be run at some point.

If you already have the node object, you might want to look at [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/6).  `node_save()` will take care of the updating of the node in the database.